# How can I check if app is being minimized from minimize icon or by clicking taskbar app icon?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I have added functionality where the app hides in the background on `window.minimize`. But I want to hide it only when the minimize button is clicked and minimize when clicked from the taskbar.

```js
win.on("minimize", function(event, args) {
    event.preventDefault();
    win.hide();
    console.log("hide min");

    win.resizable = true;

    win.resizable = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`minimize`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-minimize) seems to fire in both cases, and there doesn't appear to be a standard way of catching one, but not the other.

However, when you click on the taskbar icon, the [`blur`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-blur) event fires slightly before the `minimize` event, but if you click on the minimize button, the `minimize` event fires *first*.

This isn't the most robust solution, because of the timeout guess I had to make, but it seems to work fine:

```
mainWindow.on("minimize", () => {
    console.log(`minimized via ${blur ? "taskbar" : "titlebar"}`);
  });

  let blur = false;
  mainWindow.on("blur", () => {
    blur = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      blur = false;
    }, 100);
  })
```

However, what behavior do you want went hitting the hotkey <kbd>Windows+DownArrow</kbd>? Currently, it will count that as the titlebar case and will hide the window.

If you care about that case, you might have to hook into `before-input-event` and detect those key presses.

---

There's potentially another solution to hook into Windows messages, but that's uglier and only works on Windows.